# How do I refresh a TDBGrid?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, tdbgrid

I have a TDBGrid called `myDbGrid` that I want to update after a change to the database (insert/update/delete). How can I do this without reloading my form completely?

`myDbGrid` uses `myDataSource` and it uses `myQry` as its data set.

I've tried the following with no success:

```
myDbGrid.Refresh;
```

and

```
myDbGrid.DataSource.DataSet.Close;
myQry.Close; // '' I think this is redundant
myQry.Open;
myDbGrid.DataSource.DataSet.Refresh;
```

What have I missed?

(I'll note that the database change is not happening in the tDBGrid - it's there for display only)

Comment: Calling just `myDbGrid.DataSource.DataSet.Refresh;` should do that. `myDbGrid.Refresh;` forces the grid to repaint.

Comment: Maybe the transaction in the database is not being commited?

Comment: Bone-headed move.... I was refreshing *before* I did my database change and I couldn't see the forest for the trees. I'd close it, but since the next best Google result for my question is from E-E.com I'll leave it open for the next person. If TLama wants to post their comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted right away. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only code that is needed here is:

```
myDbGrid.DataSource.DataSet.Refresh;
```

Everything else is redundant in this particular case.

Comment: What if the changes have not been committed to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
ADOQuery.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery.SQL.Add('select* from table_name');
ADOQuery.Open;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ADOQuery, so I did:

```
ADOQuery1.Active := False;
ADOQuery1.Active := True;
```